# Insert headers and footers office.js api

Tags: ms-word, office-addins, office-js

I am trying to insert header and footers into a document using the office js API in a task pane app. I cant seem to find a way to add headers and footers to the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Headers and Footers inherit the [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598674.aspx) class and can be accessed by initializing a [Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598686.aspx). Here is [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippet-explorer/blob/master/word-snippets/sectionInsertTextHeader.js) from the Office-JS Snippet Explorer :

```js
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a proxy sectionsCollection object.
    var mySections = context.document.sections;

    // Queue a commmand to load the sections.
    context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued-up commands, 
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {

        // Create a proxy object the primary header of the first section. 
        // Note that the header is a body object.
        var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary");

        // Queue a command to insert text at the end of the header.
        myHeader.insertText("This is a header.", Word.InsertLocation.end);

        // Queue a command to wrap the header in a content control.
        myHeader.insertContentControl();

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued-up commands, 
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log("Added a header to the first section.");
        });                    
    });  
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: context.document.sections does not exist in the API. This code throws.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: I see this functionality is only in Office 2016 Desktop (& iPad) - is there a plan for when it's coming to Office Online?

Comment: @Gab Royer I am using Word 2013 and VS2015 to develop. This is a task pane add-in. The minimum requirements are Word 2013. It will work in Office 365 and Office for iPad as well. I am using v 1.1 of the office js API, this is the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

A question: how can you enable the word document to use the different header types? (First and Primary)? It seems I can set the contents of the First and Primary headers and footers, but, without manually changing the document it does not seem to use them.

I am not sure how to reword this (seems clear to me) :(, trying.

A word document uses the same header type for each page unless the document is changed to use different header types. ie, how do I replicate the attached image controls?
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6IWN.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31686421)